# Using images from SWC libraries in Apache Royale 0.9.8

Tags: visual-studio-code, swc, apache-royale

We are working on a migration project using Apache Royale and the project contains plenty of SWC files that contains JPG and PNG images.

We have been trying to use them directly from the libs but without any success. If we copy the file directly to the source folder it works. But we need to be able to refer and use the images inside the libs.

Folder structure looks like this

[image]

ascongig.json looks like this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "source-map": true,
        "targets": [
            "JSRoyale"
        ],
        "js-external-library-path": [
            "${royalelib}/js/libs/MXRoyaleJS.swc",
            "${royalelib}/js/libs/JewelJS.swc"
        ],
        "js-library-path": [
            "libs/images.swc"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "src/HelloRoyale.mxml"
    ]
}
```

And the HelloWorld.mxml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<j:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:j="library://ns.apache.org/royale/jewel"
                applicationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            internal var iconAgenda:String = "images/visualizar_agenda.png";
            internal var iconAgenda2:String = "images2/visualizar_agenda.png";
            public function init():void{
                imagem.src = iconAgenda;
                imagem2.src = iconAgenda2;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <j:initialView>
        <j:View>
            <j:beads>
                <j:VerticalLayout />
            </j:beads>
            <j:Label text="From Library" />
            <j:Image id="imagem"/>
            <j:Image src="images/afericao.png"/>
            <j:Label text="From Sources Folder"/>
            <j:Image id="imagem2"/>
            <j:Image src="images2/afericao.png"/>
        </j:View>
    </j:initialView>
</j:Application>
```

This results in this

[image]

We are using VS Code with Apache Royal 0.9.8.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I just found this question now.

Add to the asconfig.json file:

```
    "copySourcePathAssets": true,
```

like this:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "source-map": true,
    "targets": [
        "JSRoyale"
    ],
    "js-external-library-path": [
        "${royalelib}/js/libs/MXRoyaleJS.swc",
        "${royalelib}/js/libs/JewelJS.swc"
    ],
    "js-library-path": [
        "libs/images.swc"
    ]
},
"copySourcePathAssets": true,
"files": [
    "src/HelloRoyale.mxml"
]
```

}